# Image directories can be transferred wrong with ftp (placeholder for images) while moving / migrating a Magento website

Tags: image, magento, directory, uppercase, lowercase

I have a problem when transferring a Magento version into my computer with WS_FTP Pro. This gives a bug on a Magento website for displaying images.

If there are two directory names X and x (for images), the first transferred creates a directory (X or x) and the second directory is copied into the first one (so X first created, x and X are copied into X; so x first created, x and X are copied into x). So one directory is always missing and gives errors (images not found).

So my Magento transfer is absolutely instable (can miss more directories).

Comment: You have a case-sensitive-to-case-insensitive filesystem issue. Switch to a case-sensitive development environment.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I did found in Windows 7 this registry option was set to 1: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\ dword:ObCaseInsensitive; maybe because of an update; I set it to 0 (not case insensitive), I restarted the system, but the problem is still there?

Answer (score 1):

Enable case sensitivity - eee [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/configure-case-sensitivity-for-files-and-folders/aff2d548-edc3-4353-b804-af31b163bd44) at Microsoft Answers - but you may need to use a UNIX-like shell to move files around. Not sure if this will do the trick. If you can't switch your dev enviro, use VirtualBox and a Ubuntu enviro.

Comment: Thanks Ben but I find this all too risky, hackers can place EDIT.COM in your system near edit.com etc. By default it is switched on in Windows 7 (I do not change it and it does not work). The problem is for the old and new provider case sensitivity is switched on. On my system is it switched off, so I can not transfer the directories. I asked my provider if it is possible to switch this off for my account only, than fixed, I let you know

Comment: No other possibility than Magento directory structure always to zip at one provider, download to pc, upload to new provider and let the new provider unpack it. Otherwise you can loose directories. 

It would be better Magento had an option in the admin to prevent this, so to prevent, it would create double directories like x and X (case sensitive). I never experienced this problem with any sofware.